# Bash IF statement: string comparison of command output always false

Tags: bash, if-statement, gnu-screen

Hi I'm trying to write a simple bash script to attach to a screen session. If the session is not already started then it will start it and try to attach again.

The problem I'm having is with the if statement; it should compare the output from the screen command with the failure message and if they are equal go on to start the session and attach. But it's always going to the else clause, printing out the error message I was checking against :s

Both strings contain the same thing:

> "There is no screen to be attached matching sctest."

but bash thinks they are different...

Here's the bash script, what am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash

screenOutput=$(screen -aA -x sctest);
failString="There is no screen to be attached matching sctest.";

if [ "$screenOutput" = "$failString" ]; then
    echo "screen session not started. starting now...";

    # . ./init.sh

    # echo $(screen -aA -x sctest);
else
    echo "$screenOutput";
fi
```

Comment: I found the issue almost as soon as I posted. I made the if line error by removing the spaces which showed me there's a \r at the end of $screenOutput -.- If someone has an answer with a command to see these invisible characters then that would be a much appreciated accepted answer :)

Comment: what is string stored screenOutput . Please check using echo.

Comment: It fails because the output stored in `screenOutput` is terminated by `^M`. You can run `cat -vET <<< "$screenOutput"` to see the offending character.

Comment: There happens to be a option for screen: `-R` creates session if not already exist.

Comment: @alvits indeed that is true, how can I add the `^M` character to the end of the `$failString` ?

Comment: The answer posted by @CharlesDuffy is the right way to go. But for your curiosity's sake, you can set the value of `failString` like this `printf -v failString "%s%b" "There is no screen to be attached matching sctest." \\\x0d`.

Comment: That, or a `$''` literal: `failString=$'There is no screen to be attached matching sctest.\r'`

Comment: @alvits and Charles Duffy, Thanks for the help! the mad bash character strings are starting to make sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set -x` (or invoke `bash -x yourscript`) to print each line as it's evaluated with values expanded in a way that makes hidden characters visible and human-readable.

Most likely, you'll see something like the following:

```
[ 'There is no screen to be attached matching sctest' = $'There is no screen to be attached matching sctest\r' ]
```

...with the latter having a `\r` on the end. This is a carriage-return.

To remove it, you can modify your code like so:

```
screenOutput=$(screen -aA -x sctest)
screenOutput=${screenOutput%$'\r'}
```

Comment: Thank you! what can I search for to get more info on what `${screenOutput%$'\r'}` is doing, google doesn't seem to care about special characters anymore :/